# javascript: history.go(1) required to preserve ASP sessions?

Tags: javascript, session, asp-classic

I've inherited a Classic ASP app, and the former author claims that:

```
 BODY onload="javascript: history.go(1);"
```

is required to keep the site from "losing sessions"

Has anyone heard of this quirk? I can't fathom it.

Comment: I've never heard of anything like that, sounds bogus to me.

Comment: Is the code doing any sort of History.back or history.go(-n)?

Comment: I've seen this used as a way to prevent someone from pressing the back button, but is that a practical approach? Is there a newer, more efficient way?

Comment: The new, more efficient way is never to try to break the back button. You can't do it reliably and your users will justifiably hate you. If you have an application issue that you think the answer to is to break the back button you have much bigger problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like the old developer was trying to prevent users from navigating using the forward/back browser buttons. If the application was not designed to accomodate users jumping around, suddenly submitting a form from an unexpected page could absolutely ruin a session.

Putting history.go(1) in a script tag in every document forces the browser to jump forward repeatedly to the last-visited page.

Answer (score 0):

No, this will not stop sessions from (a) expiring or (b) losing the browser cookie which identifies them.  Those are the two causes for "losing sessions".  As you point out in the comments, this is typically done to hack disabling the back button.  It's still used today.